# How do you perform Mann-kendall test on multiple stations using loops?

Tags: r, loops, time-series, lapply

I've just started using R and would like to use the modifiedmk package to perform tests on monthly groundwater level data. My dataframe (GL) looks something like this

```
GL

well    year    month   value
684     1994    Jan     8.53
684     1995    Jan     8.74
684     1996    Jan     8.88
684     1997    Jan     8.24
1001    2000    Jan     9.1
1001    2001    Jan     9.2
1001    2002    Jan     9.54
1001    2003    Jan     9.68
2003    1981    Jan     55.2
2003    1982    Jan     55.8
2003    1983    Jan     56.4
2003    1984    Jan     53.2
```

First I have created a list of wells and a results_list file for printing the results

```
well_list <- unique(GL$well)
results_list <- vector("list", length(well_list))
```

Then I have created what I think is a loop

```
for(i in well_list){
  results_list[[grep(i, well_list)]] <- MannKendall(GL[,4])
}
names(results_list) <- well_list
```

but I kept getting this error

```
Error in Kendall(1:length(x), x) : length(x)<3
```

I can get this code to work (which I took from another post here) but I don't want to perform the pre-whitening method

```
for(i in well_list){
tempDF <- GL1[GL$well == i, ]
c<-acf(tempDF$value,lag.max=1)
t <- dim(c$acf)
tempDF$prewhit1<-c$acf[[t[1], t[2], t[3]]]*tempDF$value
prewhitseries<-data.frame(with(tempDF,(tempDF$value[-1] - prewhit1[ 
length(prewhit1)])))
autocordata<-cbind(tempDF[-1,],prewhitseries)
results_list[[grep(i, well_list)]] <- MannKendall(autocordata[,5])}
names(results_list) <- well_list
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do. `split()` splits along the `well` column, creating a list with a vector for each well. Only vectors of length 3 or more are kept. `MannKendall()` is then run on each of the remaining vectors using `lapply()`

```
library(Kendall)

tt <- read.table(text="
well    year    month   value
684     1994    Jan     8.53
684     1995    Jan     8.74
684     1996    Jan     8.88
684     1997    Jan     8.24
1001    2000    Jan     9.1
1001    2001    Jan     9.2
1001    2002    Jan     9.54
1001    2003    Jan     9.68
2003    1981    Jan     55.2
2003    1982    Jan     55.8
2003    1983    Jan     56.4
2003    1984    Jan     53.2
2004    1984    Jan     53.2", header=TRUE)

tt.wells <- split(tt$value, tt$well)
tt.wells <- tt.wells[lengths(tt.wells) >= 3]

lapply(tt.wells, MannKendall)

# $`684`
# tau = 0, 2-sided pvalue =1

# $`1001`
# tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =0.089429

# $`2003`
# tau = 0, 2-sided pvalue =1
```

Comment: Hi guys, that was amazing! the first solution worked but unfortunately I still had issues with the errors.  The second solution worked but without errors.  Thanks heaps - I've been trying for ages to figure this out and look how simple it was!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with `split/lapply` it is easier and more readable.

First, runs the tests.

```
sp <- split(GL, GL$well)
results_list <- lapply(sp, function(DF){
  tryCatch(MannKendall(DF[, 4]),
           error = function(e) e)
})
```

Now, get the good ones, with no errors.

```
bad <- sapply(results_list, inherits, "error")
```

And inspect them.

```
results_list[bad]
#named list()

results_list[!bad]
#$`684`
#tau = 0, 2-sided pvalue =1
#
#$`1001`
#tau = 1, 2-sided pvalue =0.089429
#
#$`2003`
#tau = 0, 2-sided pvalue =1
```